# Installing pygame on Windows (custom Python location not supported?)

Tags: windows, python-3.x, installation, pygame

I am running Python 3.5 on Windows 8. I am trying to install pygame. I downloaded and ran

```
pygame-1.9.2a0.win32-py3.2.msi (6.4 Mb)
```

from

```
http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml
```

From python I get, after starting a new session:

```
>>> import pygame
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
ImportError: No module named 'pygame'
```

How do I install? Was my PythonPath updated? Looking at sys.path, it doesn't look like it. How do I get Python to see the library? Where was the library installed? Thanks for the help.

Update1:

The first step i the pygame intsaller states "Select Python Installations - Select the locations where pygame-1.9.2a0 should be installed." Underneath that is a selection that states "Python from another location". This doesn't make sense to me. Anyone?

Update2: I solved the problem - I reinstalled python in the default location (it wasn't before). The pygame installer doesn't seem to support custom installations. Ok, fixed. Thanks all for the help.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/install/

Comment: [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)

Comment: do you use Python 32-bit or 64-bit ? This PyGame is for 32-bit Python 3.2 - not 3.5.

Comment: Both are 32-bit. The pygame installer put some files somewhere and python is not aware of them. Is there another step that has to be performed?

Answer (score 1):

Up to now, Windows binaries **must** match the Python binaries.  `...py-3.2.msi` is for 3.2 and **will not work** with 3.5.  Either get a 3.5 binary from the site you already used or use `pip` to install `pygame-1.9.2a0-cp35-none-win32.whl` from `http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/`  Use `pip install /?` to get info on how to install from somewhere other than pypi.  It might be easier to download the file to your machine first.  The site above says a bit about this.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have 32-bit python and pygame.

Comment: I am using 32-bit python and 32-bit pygame      >>> sys.version
'3.5.0 (v3.5.0:374f501f4567, Sep 13 2015, 02:16:59) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]'
>>>                The problem is that the installer just put some files somewhere but python knows nothing about it.